# Undefined statement in XML even when the some properties are working

Tags: jquery, xml

I am receiving an "Undefined" statement for some parts of my xml anyone know why? It is showing the picture, and the headline but the text is just showing up as undefined

Here is the xml:

```
<Parent>
  <Child
     land="Germany"
     headline="Beer"
     src="images/beer.png"
     text="Das klassische Schwarzbier hat seinen Ursprung in Thüringen"
     ingredients="Water, Hops"
  />
</Parent>
```

And to the JQuery

```
$(function () {

        $(window).bind('load', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "test.xml",
                async: false,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: Template
            });
        });

        function Template(xml) {

            $(xml).find('Parent').each(function () {

             /* BODY IS CREATED HERE */
               $(xml).find('Child').each(function () {
                    $('<div id="inline-' + ($(this).attr('headline')) + '" class=sensebox-container"><div class="sensebox-img"><img src="' +($(this).attr('src')) +'">' +
                    '<h3>' + ($(this ).attr('headline')) + '</h3><p>' + ($(this ).attr('text')) + '</p>').appendTo(body);
})
})
```

Comment: is </Spot> supposed to be </Parent>?

Comment: So, is the problem still occurring?

Comment: Fix your code in the example and/or check the original one for typos. As this demo [shows](http://jsfiddle.net/d94c5mqj/), it's fine to use `text` attribute.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd remove the extra parens around the attr retrieval; they make it harder to think about the code.

Comment: In fact, I'd rather have `$(this).attr(...)` replaced with `this.getAttribute(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are attaching a `load` event to the window under the DOMReady event. This is pointless as the window load event fires before the DOMReady event, so you may as well just fire the AJAX request at that point.

The issue with your XML parsing is that the `Parent` element is the root, so you need to use `filter`, not `find` to access it. Finally, in the `appendTo`, unless `body` is a variable holding a jQuery object it should be quoted so you select the `body` element. Here's the full example:

```js
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: Template
    });

    function Template(xml) {
        $(xml).filter('Parent').each(function () {
            $(xml).find('Child').each(function () {
                $('<div id="inline-' + $(this).attr('headline') + '" class=sensebox-container"><div class="sensebox-img"><img src="' + $(this).attr('src') +'"><h3>' + $(this ).attr('headline') + '</h3><p>' + $(this ).attr('text') + '</p>').appendTo('body');
            })
        })
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7nrppc26/)

Note also that your HTML does not contain closing tags for the `div` elements you open, and I removed the `async: false` property as you shouldn't even bother with AJAX if you're going to make is synchronous.

Comment: Nice answer, but I'm really sure the code in the original post was just for example (as it won't even show headline and image as the OP mentioned).

Comment: I'm sure it was an example, but the main point of my answer what to point out that trying to use `find` to get the root element is never going to work.

Comment: fantastic thanks very much for that informative answer